# What's the difference between Mat::clone and Mat::copyTo?

Tags: opencv

I know 'copyTo' can handle mask. But when mask is not needed, can I use both equally?

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone

Comment: without mask both are same..

Comment: Thanks. I should read source code not just documents.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Actually, they are **NOT** the same even without mask.

The major difference is that when the destination matrix and the source matrix have the same type and size, `copyTo` will not change the address of the destination matrix, while `clone` will always allocate a new address for the destination matrix.

This is important when the destination matrix is copied using copy assignment operator before `copyTo` or `clone`. For example,

Using `copyTo`:

```
Mat mat1 = Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_32F);
Mat mat2 = mat1;
Mat mat3 = Mat::zeros(1, 5, CV_32F);
mat3.copyTo(mat1);
cout << mat1 << endl;
cout << mat2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Using `clone`:

```
Mat mat1 = Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_32F);
Mat mat2 = mat1;
Mat mat3 = Mat::zeros(1, 5, CV_32F);
mat1 = mat3.clone();
cout << mat1 << endl;
cout << mat2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 33):

This is the implementation of `Mat::clone()` function:

```
inline Mat Mat::clone() const
{
  Mat m;
  copyTo(m);
  return m;
}
```

So, as @rotating_image had mentioned, if you don't provide `mask` for `copyTo()` function, it's same as `clone()`.

Comment: Whats the difference from clone to assignment? Like: Mat m1; Mat m2; m1 = m2;

Comment: What is the `const` after `Mat::clone()` ?

Comment: What you wrote is not right. See the answer below of @yangjie and OpenCV documentation: "When the operation mask is specified, if the Mat::create call shown above reallocates the matrix, the newly allocated matrix is initialized with all zeros before copying the data." but when you DO NOT provide a mask data are copied without reallocation, this means that other Mat pointing to that matrix will have values modified!

Answer (score 24):

`Mat::copyTo` is for when you already have a destination `cv::Mat` that (may be or) is already allocated with the right data size. `Mat::clone` is a convenience for when you know you have to allocate a new `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score 3):

copyTo doesn't allocate new memory in the heap which is faster.