# Can't understand the behaviour of cv2::absdiff : c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using `cv2::absdiff()` for subtracting a scalar from an image Matrix. The code I am using is:

```
  double min;
  double max;
  Scalar mean;
  Scalar std_dev;

  minMaxLoc(img_a_color_planes[1], &min, &max);
  meanStdDev(img_a_color_planes[1], mean, std_dev);

  Mat img_a_color_planes[3];
  split(img_a, img_a_color_planes); 
  Mat oper = img_a_color_planes[1];

  absdiff(oper, mean, oper);
  divide(oper, std_dev, oper);
  multiply(oper, 10, oper);
  add(oper, mean, oper);
```

In here, I specifically copied the green channel of `img_a` into the `Mat oper`, inspite of output matrix `oper` being specified in `absdiff`. Even then, the green color channel `img_a_color_planes[1]` is being affected. I don't understand the reason for this. How can I avoid this?
Here is how my `img_a` is getting affected after the `absdiff` operation:

Initial `img_a` :

[image]

After the `absdiff` operation:

[image]

Comment: What are mean and std_dev? Green only, or whole image?

Comment: They are for green channel only. I have edited my code.

Comment: `Mat oper = img_a_color_planes[1].clone();`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it keeps working on the same matrix if not cloned.

Comment: @Miki. You should turn that into an answer

Comment: Sure thing. I am on a point wh***ng spree right about now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Mat oper = img_a_color_planes[1];` does not make a copy of the underlying array, just the header data. The same applies to the [copy constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat%28const%20Mat&%20m%29).

You need to make an independent copy to avoid making changes to the original image. One way to do that is via the `clone()` method: `Mat oper = img_a_color_planes[1].clone();`. Cloning uses `copyTo()` under the hood: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15688165/2988730.

Quoting [`Mat` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat):

> Use a copy constructor or assignment operator where there can be an array or expression on the right side (see below). As noted in the introduction, the array assignment is an O(1) operation because it only copies the header and increases the reference counter. The `Mat::clone()` method can be used to get a full (deep) copy of the array when you need it.